# Как сделать, чтобы бот упоминал пользователя использовавшегося "Modals" после одобрения/отказа на выдачу роли по кнопки

Tags: javascript

у меня вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы бот упоминал пользователя использовавшегося "Modals" после одобрения/отказа на выдачу роли по кнопки.
Например:
[Вот тут он упоминает(указано зелёным)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRgyU.png)
[Вот здесь он должен упоминать пользователя(указано красным цветом), который был обозначен зеленым цветом на предыдущем скриншоте.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uetil.png)
[Вот так по итогу должно быть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn9Qf.png)
А так хочу задать вопрос как сделать, чтобы бот выдавал роль по ид человеку, которому была одобрена роль и и удалял сообщение, которое было показано на первом скриншоте.
Ниже прикладываю коды:
`interactionCreate.3`

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'prav_zap') {
            const name1 = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('modal_prav_nick')
            const embed_zap_prav = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0xffd700)
                .setTitle('Рассмотрение заявки на запрос роли')
                .setAuthor({ name: 'Arizona RP: Cave Creek', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/rQ31Qkw.png' })
                .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/hboqPFo.png')
                .setDescription(`**Пользователь <@${interaction.user.id}> создал запрос на роль:**\n**__Сотрудник правительства__**\n**Устанавливаемый ник после одобрения:**\n**__[gov] ${name1}__**\n \n**Рассмотреть обязаны:**\n<@&1008104664434233436>\n<@&1008107737315541106>`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'Sirius Version 2.0.2 (build 0008)\nStatus: Ведутся работы ', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/sK0QIDp.png' })

            const odo_prav = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('odo_prav')
                .setLabel('Одобрить выдачу')
                .setEmoji('✔')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);

            const dob_role_prav = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(odo_prav);

            const can_prav = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId('can_prav')
                .setLabel('Отказать в выдаче')
                .setEmoji('✖')
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);

            const ork_prav = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(can_prav);
```

`interactionCreate.4`

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'odo_prav') {
            const embed_odo_prav = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0xffd700)
                .setTitle('Уведомление')
                .setAuthor({ name: 'Arizona RP: Cave Creek', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/rQ31Qkw.png' })
                .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/hboqPFo.png')
                .setDescription(`**Пользователь <@${interaction.user.id}> одобрил выдачу роли: <@&1008111977152909342> пользователю <@${interaction.user.id}>**`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'Sirius Version 2.0.2 (build 0008)\nStatus: Ведутся работы ', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/sK0QIDp.png' })

            const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1067475480015556698');
            channel.send({ content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [embed_odo_prav] });
        } else if (interaction.customId === 'can_prav') {
            const embed_can_prav = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(0xffd700)
                .setTitle('Уведомление')
                .setAuthor({ name: 'Arizona RP: Cave Creek', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/rQ31Qkw.png' })
                .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/hboqPFo.png')
                .setDescription(`**Пользователь <@${interaction.user.id}> отказал в выдачи роли: <@&1008111977152909342> пользователю <@${interaction.user.id}>**`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'Sirius Version 2.0.2 (build 0008)\nStatus: Ведутся работы ', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/sK0QIDp.png' })

            const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1067475480015556698');
            channel.send({ content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>`, embeds: [embed_can_prav] });
        }
    }
});
```

Версия discord.js v14.9.0

Искал ответ в интернете, но не нашёл решения